# populating DB with million entries

Tags: java, mysql

I want to populate MySQL database with million entries,

I tried using Data generator, but i was able to get only 200 entries though i give 1000 as input, which takes a lot of time for populating.

Also tried using .txt file LOAD FILE LOCAL INFILE method for populating, but get an error as FILE NOT FOUND though the file exists in my local directory (ERRCODE: 2 & ERRCODE: 22).

I was thinking is there any better way for populating DB with million entries for performance and if so can somebody suggest me with ideas resolving my query?????

**how to populate my db with million values**????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [data generator](http://www.generatedata.com/#generator). It allows you to generate precisely the data you want (you can choose columns, etc...).

Comment: I tried using data generator but it gives me max of 200 rows though i give 1000 rows as input..!!!!

Comment: The source code is available for you to use and remove the limit. The sample web app you were using limits to 200rows as to avoid being overloaded by multiple people trying to generate millions of records. Download the source code from the Download tab, remove the limit and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [generate-dummy-test-data-for-mysql-using-routines](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/generate-dummy-test-data-for-mysql-using-routines)
or [generating-dummy-data-for-my-web-application-looking-for-dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187931/generating-dummy-data-for-my-web-application-looking-for-dictionaries)